# Unhide rows based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I am having difficulties with my code.  What I am trying to do is when the Number in cell D8 goes up it will unhide a block of rows.  Here is the following code:

```
Sub Unhide_Rows(ByVal Target As Range)
If Range("D8").Value > 1 Then
    Select Case Target.Value
        Case "2": Rows("17:36").Hidden = True: Rows("10:16").Hidden = False
        Case "3": Rows("21:37").Hidden = True: Rows("10:20").Hidden = False
        Case "4": Rows("25:37").Hidden = True: Rows("10:24").Hidden = False
        Case "5": Rows("29:37").Hidden = True: Rows("10:29").Hidden = False
        Case "6": Rows("33:37").Hidden = True: Rows("10:33").Hidden = False
        Case "7": Rows("10:37").Hidden = False: Rows("55:56").Hidden = True

    End Select
End If
End Sub
```

Another Issue I am running into is when I try to run the code in VBA it opens a macro box and wants me to select a macro, but I do not want to connect the code to a macro...?

Comment: How is your sub called? Also should it re-hide rows if the value changes? D8 == Target? what is target otherwise?

Comment: if the value goes down it should rehide rows acordingly

Comment: I see that each step hides and unhides rows now, can you update your question to show how you're calling your sub, and what Target is.

Comment: I am new to VBA... What my target is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a little bit of a guess as I'm not quite sure what all the variables in your code example are for.

[Example Workbook Here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/10316127/Book1.xlsm)

Open the VBA Editor (Alt+F11)

Insert the following Sub into a module (in the VBA Editor, in the main menu, Insert->Module)

[image: showing module1 in vbaeditor]

```
Sub Toggle_Rows()
Dim Sheet As Worksheet: Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Change Sheet1 to the name of your sheet

    Select Case CStr(Sheet.Range("D8").Value2)
    Case "2"
        Sheet.Rows("17:36").Hidden = True
        Sheet.Rows("10:16").Hidden = False
    Case "3"
        Sheet.Rows("21:37").Hidden = True
        Sheet.Rows("10:20").Hidden = False
    Case "4"
        Sheet.Rows("25:37").Hidden = True
        Sheet.Rows("10:24").Hidden = False
    Case "5"
        Sheet.Rows("29:37").Hidden = True
        Sheet.Rows("10:29").Hidden = False
    Case "6"
        Sheet.Rows("33:37").Hidden = True
        Sheet.Rows("10:33").Hidden = False
    Case "7"
        Sheet.Rows("10:37").Hidden = False
        Sheet.Rows("55:56").Hidden = True
    Case Else
        ' none
    End Select

End Sub
```

Now In the "Project Explorer" (usually on the left of the VBA Editor) open the code module for the worksheet you are working with (Sheet1 in my example) add the following code.

[image: showing sheet1 code in vbaeditor]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Msgbox Prompt:="Target.Address=" & Target.Address ' remove this line after debugging.

If Target.Address = "$D$8" Then
    Toggle_Rows
End If

End Sub
```

**Update**

Please ensure you've copied the code into the correct modules! I've added one line to the `Worksheet_Change` sub for debugging purposes. Please add it to your code, change the value in `D8` and tell me what is displayed in the message box.

**Notes**

I think you may have re-named `Worksheet_Change` to `Unhide_Rows` in your code example, which you cannot do. (you can, but it will no longer work as it did)

Also, Subs that do not have arguments can be run from the VBA code editor. Subs WITH arguments (like yours) cannot, as there is no way to specify the argument unless you use the immediate window or have another sub (without arguments) that calls it for you.

```
Sub HelloWorld(ByVal Text As String) ' cant be run directly
    Debug.print "Hello World! " & Text)
End Sub

Sub CallHello() ' can be run directly in the vba editor
    HelloWorld "Im Alive!"
End Sub
```

You could also call "HelloWorld" using the Immediate window.

```
HelloWorld "Im Alive!" (press enter)
```

**Update 2**

Your scrollbar isn't triggering the `Worksheet_Change` event, im not sure that you can make them do this.

However, the scroll bar has its own change event sub.

Open the code module for the worksheet the scrollbar is on (Sheet2 I believe) In the top left dropdown box (where it says "(general)") there will be an item for your scrollbar ("ScrollBar1" unless you renamed it). Selecting this should add the change event code, if not you will need to select "Change" from the right-hand dropdown box.

Code like the following should work.

```
Private Sub ScrollBar1_Change()
    Toggle_Rows
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked great!  How to I make it so that every time cell "D8" is changed the code will run though?

Comment: If you copied both sections of code into the places I described then it should already do that.

Comment: I copied both in like said but when i change cell "D8" the function is not working on its own.  I have to manualy run the macro for it to work

Comment: If you open the code module for the sheet D8 is on, then in the dropdown box at top left (where it says "General") select "Worksheet" and then in the right dropdown box select "Change". Sometimes it doesn't like having code like that pasted in. (you may need to copy the contents of my "Worksheet_Change" into the new one if an empty one appears.

Comment: when I change the value in D8 no message box apears... nothing happens.

Comment: the macro works so when I change D8 and then run Toggle_Rows it runs the code successfuly it just wont do it on its own

Comment: Please look at the example workbook I've added, ensure that you've copied everything into the correct location (and not modified it incorrectly). I cant really help any further than that.

Comment: I made sure that it is put in the way you show.  The only differense I see is that the sheet that D8 is on is sheet 2 but the code is in the right place and all the sheet names are correct

Comment: if D8 cell is on Sheet2, then the code for the **Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)** should be in the code module for *Sheet2* (right-click on Sheet2 (in Excel worksheet) and click '*View Code*'

Comment: For his workbook yes, my example workbook uses `Sheet1!D8` (I do say to use the code module for the worksheet he is using). As he's using a scroll bar to change the value of *D8* it does not trigger the sheet_change event.