# Macro to run when cell value changes

Tags: excel, vba

I am realy not sure what the problem with this code is or if it is a problem with the formatting of my worksheet but the following code will not automatically run when the value of `D8` changes:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$D$8" Then
   Toggle_Rows
End If
End Sub
```

Is it a formating issue or a code issue?

Comment: What happens if you `Debug.print` the `Target` value?

Comment: How would I Debug.Print ?

Comment: It is in sheet 2 under Microsoft Excel Objects

Comment: Any other ideas why this isnt working?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `If Target.Address = `$D$8`. Then, if you change the value of D8, what happens?

Comment: is D8 a merged cell? if you don't understand debug try using a Msgbox(Target.Address) as the first line of the worksheet change event it will display what cell is changing.

Comment: @davidvandervieren You may have disabled Events. Goto the `Immediate` window in the VBE. Type in `Application.EnableEvents = True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing your question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772686/unhide-rows-based-on-cell-value)

I'd like you to try this:

In the work book goto the sheet that you wish to change the value of D8  and have the code run. 
At the bottom of Excel right click the Tab with the name of that sheet and then select View Code

At the top of your Code window you should see the word "(General)".

Click on the drop down and select "WorkSheet", you should see a new Sub called

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

You can delete those lines. Now to the right of where you selected Worksheet theres another drop down this one should say "SelectionChange" Click on that then Select the word "Change" from the drop down. You should see another new sub

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

In between those 2 lines is where you want

```
If Target.Address = "$D$8" Then
   Toggle_Rows
End If
```

Comment: This works.  the problem that I was running into before is that i was using a spinner to change the number in cell D8 and for some reason the cell didnt recognize the change when I used the spinner... but it works with manually entering in the data

Comment: This isn't actually an answer to your question, it restates exactly what you initially posted.

Comment: @DavidVanderVieren So, You assigned the Toggle_Rows sub to the Spinner  Change? Right click on the spinner use Assign Macro and select Toggle_Rows from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but a way to debug. as this works for me both manually and via code.

Try one of the following to see the value you get:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    MsgBox Target.Address        

    Debug.Print Target.Address

    If Target.Address = "$D$8" Then 
       Toggle_Rows
    End If    
End Sub
```