# Hide multiple rows on sheet based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I’m trying, with Excel 2013, to hide and unhide rows when a cell is a certain value.

It's a form which should expand based on answers given.

When C16 = YES hide rows 18:22

When C16 = NO hide rows 24:38

When C16 =blank hide rows 18:38

When L43 = YES unhide rows 43:68 (if it’s not yes a zero is displayed)

I have tried 2 methods.

First: Into the worksheet  - selected change in the top right dropdown

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Range("A18:A22").EntireRow.Hidden = (Range("$C$16").Value = "Yes")

    Range("A24:A38").EntireRow.Hidden = (Range("$C$16").Value = "NO")

    Range("A18:A38").EntireRow.Hidden = (Range("$C$16").Value = "")

    Range("A43:A68").EntireRow.Hidden = (Range("$L$43").Value = "0")

End Sub
```

Second: code from here:

[Unhide rows based on cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772686/unhide-rows-based-on-cell-value)

Using both of these methods only one of the changes seems to go ahead. So cell C16 is changed but that means range L43 is ignored

Also when the cell was blank it didn’t change anything. It remained as is and didn’t hide the columns as required.

Answer (score 3):

Your ranges overlap so even if `C16 = "Yes"` the line `C16 = ""` will override it and unhide it. `L42` is probably also a number where as you're comparing it to a text value try using the following instead. Your code would run on every single change in your sheet as well so have also updated it to only run when either `C16` or `L43` is changed

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Me
        If Not Intersect(Target, Union(.Range("C16"), .Range("L43"))) Is Nothing Then
            .Range("A18:A38").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Select Case LCase(.Range("C16").Value2)
                Case "yes"
                    .Range("A18:A22").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Case "no"
                    .Range("A24:A38").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Case Else
                    .Range("A18:A38").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End Select

            .Range("A43:A68").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Select Case LCase(.Range("L43").Value2)
                Case "yes"
                    .Range("A43:A68").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                Case Else
                    .Range("A43:A68").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End Select
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

***After comments***

I'd break this into two from your comments. The first would watch the dropdown and execute on the change of that cell. The second would update using the calculate event. Put these Subs in the sheets where applicable

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Me
        If Not Intersect(Target, Union(.Range("C16"), .Range("L43"))) Is Nothing Then
            .Range("A18:A38").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Select Case LCase(.Range("C16").Value2)
                Case "yes"
                    .Range("A18:A22").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Case "no"
                    .Range("A24:A38").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Case Else
                    .Range("A18:A38").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End Select
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With Me
        .Range("A43:A68").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Select Case LCase(.Range("L43").Value2)
            Case "yes"
                .Range("A43:A68").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Case Else
                .Range("A43:A68").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End Select
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: So this one worked really well when untested it out, seems to be my preferred option as I don't need anything in a module. One thing that I have messed up on is my logic. The cell is L43 is changed based on a formula. So it looks up data from another sheet and will return YES or 0. Is it possible to make the sheet hide from the formula result. If it's a pain I will just create a new drop down and make the change happen on the sheet?

Comment: Tom..this is incredible. Thank you. Is it the line application.enableevents that is allowing this to happen? Just looking to understand what this is doing.

Comment: The `Application.EnableEvents` is stopping the Event from calling it itself and ending up in recursion. i.e. Calculation calls the calculate event. Change from event causes calculation which in turn calls the event and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Rows("18:68").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    opt = UCase(.Range("C16").Value)
    Select Case opt
    Case "YES"
        Rows("18:22").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case "NO"
        Rows("24:38").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case ""
        Rows("18:38").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Invalid option in cell C16."
    End Select
    If UCase(.Range("L43").Value) = "Yes" Then
        Rows("43:68").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        MsgBox "Invalid option in cell L43."
    End Select
End With
```

...though I didn't understand what you wanted to be '0'.

Comment: If you're using `Rows` you don't need to use `EntireRow`